# gcc runtime declaration of static and auto variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am compiling my C code using the gcc compiler

My code is

```
main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    int a[i];
}
```

... and it executes it without any warning. However, if I use:

```
main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    static int a[i];
}
```

... I get an error message saying the size of array is not constant.

If execution of program starts at `main` function it should not give such error.
and if static data is allocated first before start of `main()`, how is the compiler able to generate such errors during during compile time?

Comment: Technically, the first shouldn't be allowed either. The fact that it is is a gcc extension, I believe.

Comment: @dlf tht only applies to C++

Comment: you are using VLAs, which are not allowed to be static or extern

Comment: @CoolGuy i takes value through scanf()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables length arrays are not allowed to be static from the draft C99 standard section `6.7.5.2` *Array declarators* paragraph *2* says (*emphasis mine*):

> An ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3) that has a variably modified type shall have
>   either block scope and no linkage or function prototype scope. **If an identifier is declared to be an object with static storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.**

In C++ variable length arrays are not part of the standard and are a compiler extension but `gcc` should be be following the C99 rules there as well.

Comment: Does this means that VLA is always consumes stack portion?

Comment: @Vagish that standard does not specify that but in practice yes, they are allocated on the stack.